# Use MVC routing to alias a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a controller called `InstallationController`, and a fancy report representation of an installation called a *Rate Card*, but the end user insists on calling installations themselves *Rate Cards*.  I would like him to see the URL http://site/RateCard/Edit/3, where this gets routed actually as http://site/Installation/Edit/3.  How can I do this in MVC 3 RC2?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A couple of options are, you can either rename the controller to `RateCardController`, or add a new route that directs to the Installation controller, like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
               "RateCard", // Route name
               "RateCard/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
               new { controller = "Installation", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
               );
```

Comment: Do I add that after the default route?  Doesn't seem to be working - I just get a 404 using http://site/RateCard

Comment: @ProfK: If you have other controllers as well, this one should go **before** default route because otherwise default route tried to route to `RateCardsController` which doesn't exist. The other option is that you put this route **after** default route but you will have to add a contraint to default route to ignore *RateCards* controller name.