# ASP.NET MVC 3 Controller routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing

So I am a little confused as to how to handle some MVC Routing

I have an AdminController

```
    public class AdminController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Admin/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Users()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Books()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Which works fine. So I can go to /Admin/Books

This is the admin menu for managing books.  Now in there I'd like to be able to route like

```
/Admin/Books/ViewBook/10
or
/Admin/Books/Add
```

Something like that.  I can't seem to grasp how to route these things that way.
I made a controller

AdminBookController

```
   public class AdminBooksController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /AdminBooks/
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult BookDetails(Guid guid)
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult BookDetails(ModifyBook Book)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            return View("Book successfully Edited!");
        else
            return View();
    }
}
```

}

but I don't want it to be /AdminBooks I feel like /Admin/Books/Action/Param is much nicer.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want those urls to map to your AdminBooks controller, you'll need to map the following routes (in this order):

```
// maps /Admin/Books/ViewBook/{id} to AdminBooksController.BookDetails(id)
routes.MapRoute(
    "AdminBooks_ViewBook", // Route name
    "Admin/Books/ViewBook/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "AdminBooks", action = "BookDetails", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

// maps /Admin/Books/{action}/{id} to AdminBooksController.{Action}(id)
routes.MapRoute(
    "AdminBooks_Default", // Route name
    "Admin/Books/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "AdminBooks", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Note: be sure to put these mappings before the default MVC route.

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating an Admin Area and adding a BookController to that Area.  See the following link for a walkthrough:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new route in your Global.asax file.

See this question:

[Use MVC routing to alias a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464934/use-mvc-routing-to-alias-a-controller)