# SEO friendly URLs for static cshtml pages in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller, seo

I am junior at web development and MVC and I just stuck on creating SEO friendly URLs.

I have a CSHTML page in View folder named bond.cshtml.
I added the following controller

```
public ActionResult Bond()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

URL that I have now is mywebsite/{controller}/**bond**
I do not like such URL as it is not SEO-friendly. 
I want to have such URL: mywebsite/{controller}/**what-is-bond**

So basically I want to be able to generate URL with some custom text.
How can I do this? This is just a static page, with text and pictures inside.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to add a new route that maps to an existing controller.

[Use MVC routing to alias a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464934/use-mvc-routing-to-alias-a-controller)

Answer (score 0):

You can register a custom ActionFilterAttribute  to add the id from text.
See http://haacked.com/archive/2010/02/21/manipulating-action-method-parameters.aspx/

The main method is this

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    var slug = filterContext.RouteData.Values["slug"] as string;
    if(slug != null)
    {
      int id;
      Slugs.TryGetValue(slug, out id);
      filterContext.ActionParameters["id"] = id;
    }
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
  }
```